# i18n vue Multiples archivos por idioma

Tags: vue.js, i18n

hay alguna manera de que coja, 4 archivos por idioma para no tenerlo todo dentro de un mismo archivo? Lo tengo puesto asi, pero no lo coge :

```
Vue.use(VueI18n)

const messages = {
  es: { ESLabels, ESMenu, ESMessages, ESToolbars },
  en: { USLabels, USMenu, USMessages, USToolbars },
  it: { ITLabels, ITMenu, ITMessages, ITToolbars },
  pt: { PTLabels, PTMenu, PTMessages, PTToolbars }
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'es',
  messages
})

OnesaitLocale.i18n((key, value) => i18n.t(key, value))

export default i18n
```

Answer (score 0):

Sí, tendrías que crear una carpeta en donde alojar archivos js(ejemplo carpeta lang) dentro de ellas crear tus archivos de mensajes.

```
import { messages } from './lang/locales';
const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'es',
    messages
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

La estructura de los archivos js sería algo así:
Para usarlo tendrías que llamarlo de esta manera {{ $t('messages.welcome') }}

```
export const messages= {
    en: {
        welcome: 'Welcome'        
    },
    es: {
        welcome: 'Bienvenido'
    },
    it: {
       welcome: ''
    },
    pt: {
       welcome: ''
    }
};
```